# MFC/C++ equivalent of VB's AppActivate

Tags: c++, vb6, mfc

`AppActivate` seems to be what i need, I am fairly sure there must be an c++/mfc equivalent. Is there one?

Comment: Can you please post simple C++ program to activate Untitled - Notepad.
Thanks in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try these:

```
SetForegroundWindow(FindWindow(NULL, "window title"));
// or
SetForegroundWindow(AfxGetMainWnd());
```

Comment: Yep, SetForegroundWindow(HWND) worked fine. Sometimes the library is just too big to find the function you need.